# Does Allah forgive zina?

Tags: halal-haram, zina, forgiveness

Does Allah forgive zina? With a unmarried man and unmarried woman?

I assume so because Allah is Ar-Rahman and Ar-Rahim

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We have many similar questions here just search by [tag:zina]-tag and you will certainly find some usefull answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. **Indeed, Allah forgives all sins**. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." (39:53)

and

> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Allah, the Exalted, has said: 'O son of Adam, I forgive you as long as you pray to Me and hope for My forgiveness, whatever sins you have committed. O son of 'Adam, I do not care if your sins reach the height of the heaven, **then you ask for my forgiveness, I would forgive you**..." ([Al-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/442))

As Allah says, he forgives all sins provided you repent, realize that you have done a sin, and never do it again.